# Registration Pages for individuals and Organisations

Tags: contacts, joomla

How can I create new registration pages for individuals or organisations using the default CiviCRM forms?

Comment: hi, could you take a step back and explain what's your aim? what is this that you are trying to do that doesn't work with search?

Comment: and pls confirm what you mean by "the existing pages" since there are a number of ways already of adding new contacts.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking can an organization register for an event using an online CiviCRM registration page, then the answer is no - or not without a customization - the CiviCRM database does allows it.

In general, the online forms for contributions, membership, and registration have built in logic that assumes the user completing the form is an individual user.